# Amazon S3 get size for particular object and files and folders in it

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am storing each my users data in a bucket with his username object inside a bucket. like my bucket is "my.bucket/bob1" "my.bucket/bob2" and so on. I can get the size of the bucket by using the Amazon S3. `$s3->get_bucket_filesize($bucket,true);`
 But i need to calculate the size of the "my.bucket/bob1" I tried to use

```
$s3->get_object_filesize($bucket, "bob1");
```

But this returns only the size of that object and which is 0 as on my client side i am treating it like a folder.

But i need to get the size of the users folder level in an efficient way for cost and time.

**EDIT:**

Used Below code But this is very slow, i have thousands of files from 1KB to 1GB+ and this code is taking too much time.

```
    function get_size($bucket,$path,$s3){
    $size = 0;

    $response = $s3->list_objects($bucket,array(
    'prefix' => $path.'/'

));
        foreach ($response->body as $object)
        {
            //print_r($object);
             $object->Key.'('.$object->Size.')</br>';
            $size  = $size+$object->Size;

        }
       // $size = number_format($size / 1024 / 1024, 2); 

        return $size;
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following code to get your folder size. This will return 0 if there is no files in it, otherwise this will sum size of all files in the folder and return you the size in GB, MB, or KB.

```
public function FolderSize($folder) {
    $s3 = new S3Client([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.region'),
        'credentials' => [
            'key' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.key'),
            'secret' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.secret'),
        ],
    ]);

    $size = 0;
    $bucket = "your bucket name";
    $objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
        "Bucket" => $bucket, // or config('filesystems.disks.s3.bucket'),
        "Prefix" => $folder
    ));
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        $size = $size+$object['Size'];
    }

    return $this->formatSizeUnits($size);
     
    
}
public function formatSizeUnits($bytes) {
    if ($bytes >= 1073741824) {
        $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1073741824, 2) . ' GB';
    } elseif ($bytes >= 1048576) {
        $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1048576, 2) . ' MB';
    } elseif ($bytes >= 1024) {
        $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1024, 2) . ' KB';
    } elseif ($bytes > 1) {
        $bytes = $bytes . ' bytes';
    } elseif ($bytes == 1) {
        $bytes = $bytes . ' byte';
    } else {
        $bytes = '0 bytes';
    }
    return $bytes;
}
```

Comment: You do not have to use public before the function name if you are not using the function inside of a class.

Answer (score 0):

Use following two functions:

First to retrieve all objects:

```
$objs = $awsobject->fetchObjs('folderpath/','bucket_name');
```

Second to get the size of the retrieved objects

```
$used = $awsobject->folderSizeRawPrettyFromSource($objs);
```

It would return size in MBs.

Answer (score -2):

Please try the below code using [getObjectInfo](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation#getObjectInfo).

```
$objInfo = $s3->getObjectInfo($bucket, "bob1");
echo $objInfo['size'];
```

Comment: I am using the latest version AWS- PHP SDK and this method is not listed there.

Comment: This function is from 2007.